# Cannot source venv using makefile

Tags: bash, python, make, pip, makefile

The Makefile inside project root

```
# Makefile

.PHONY: help
help:
    @echo "Commands:"
    @echo "venv   : creates development environment."

# Environment
.ONESHELL:
venv:
    python3 -m venv venv
    source venv/bin/activate
```

When i run:

```
make venv
```

I get the following Error:

```
$ make venv
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate 

/bin/sh: 2: source: not found
Makefile:15: recipe for target 'venv' failed
make: *** [venv] Error 127
```

However, running the commands outside the Makefile is no problem at all.
Any ideas?

Comment: [Makefile default shell is /bin/sh which does not implement source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43566158/7097493)

Comment: +1 ... as well, each line in a Makefile is executed in a separate shell iirc. What exactly is your end goal here?

Comment: @steeldriver I changed it in a way that all commands are executed in one single shell. The ultimate goal was to create a virtual environment, source it, pip install setup tools and use the setup.py to install all dependencies